# ColorDiff - change colors

Tags: shell, linux-terminal

Is there any way to change color scheme used for color diff ?
By default it uses red and blue
But i cant see blue on my LCD at all....

Id prefer eg yellow or green

I think I read about some cfg file but cant find any reference to that

Tool website:
https://www.colordiff.org/

Found below info in MAN, but have no idea how to set color schemes ...

> The colour schemes can be read from a central configuration file or
>   from a local user ~/.colordiffrc file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally Ive found example

```
# Example colordiffrc file for dark backgrounds
#
# Set banner=no to suppress authorship info at top of
# colordiff output
banner=no
#.
# available colours are: white, yellow, green, blue,
#                        cyan, red, magenta, black,
#                        darkwhite, darkyellow, darkgreen,
#                        darkblue, darkcyan, darkred,
#                        darkmagenta, darkblack
#

# this works better on terminals with white background:
##plain=darkblack
##newtext=darkcyan
##oldtext=darkmagenta
##diffstuff=darkgreen
##cvsstuff=black

plain=yellow
newtext=darkcyan
oldtext=darkmagenta
diffstuff=darkgreen
cvsstuff=darkred
```

Comment: "Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources"?

Comment: @harrymc - it was miss-click apparently  :)